# PHP not telling me that user is already registered

Tags: php, html

edit: I finally fixed it! After checking if there is a duplicate email or name, I stated that the name/email address had already been registered and then I created a redirect statement to redirect the user back to the signup.php page, and therefore I have no time to be able to read it :)
Hope this helps anyone else who views this post :)
Thanks for all your help guys!!

I have a simple sign up form that works perfectly well. It checks if the user already exists in the table/database and if not doesn't sign them up, else, it signs them up. The only problem is that it is not telling the user that there is another user in the database with the same name and/or email. I have the mysqli_errno() function to tell me if there are any errors, but since there is not, it doesn't give me errrors. The weird thing is that if any of the fields are left blank, it tells me that I have to fill in all fields, which is correct!

Here is my signup code: 
HTML form:

```
<form class="form" action="register.php" method="post">
                <div class="formrow">
                    <label> Full Name </label><input name="name" class="formfield name" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="formrow">   
                    <label> Email (@wbhs.co.za or @wghs.co.za)</label><input name="email" class="formfield email" type="email" />
                </div>
                <div class="formrow">   
                    <label> Password (Minimum 8 characters)</label><input name="password" class="formfield pass" type="password" />
                    </div>
              <div class="formrow"> 
                    <label> Confirm Password </label><input class="formfield pass" type="password" name="cPassword"/>      
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button pullright submit">

            <p><br /></p>
            </div>
            <p><br /></p>
            <div class="contentfooter">
              <label>Sign Up Form</label> <a class="callright">Enjoy The Connection! Be Connected</i></a>
              </form>
```

php signup code:

```
session_start();
        include ("database/connect.php");

        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $name = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name'])));
        $email = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email'])));
        $password = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password'])));
        $cPassword = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cPassword'])));
    }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if ($name == "" or $email == "" or $password == "" or $cPassword == "") {
            echo "<div style='color:red'>No fields can be left blank!</div>";
        } else if ($name != "" && $email != "" && $password != "" && $cPassword != "") {
            $queryCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) < 1) {
                mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name','$email', '$password')") or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
                header('location:index.php');
        } } else if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) > 0){
            echo "<div style='color:red'>" . mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
            header('location:register.php');
        }
    }
```

I also have a similar problem with my login code, HTML code is mostly the same, except for the necessary changes, such as the action attribute set to login.php

PHP code:

```
session_start();
    include('database/connect.php');

    echo $_SESSION['id'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if  (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $email = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]));
            $password = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]));
        }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($count == 1) { 
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            header('location:index.php');
    } else {
        echo "Email/Password is incorrect";
    }
}
```

If I supply an email address and password that are signed-up/in the database table, it redirects me to the index page, which is correct. But if I enter a wrong username or password, it just refreshes the page and doesn't tell me anything!!!
plz help! I cannot seem to fix this :)
Thanx in advance :)

PS: Everything is fine with the connect.php file.

Comment: This is basic troubleshooting. What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: When you run in the database it return some row?

Comment: Please tell me you aren't storing password unencrypted in the database?!?!?! You really should be using prepared statements when you are querying with user supplied data.

Comment: "} } else if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) > 0){"
Two closing braces at the beginning of this line?? There should be one if you want to "else" this statement with rowCount < 0 condition. Otherwise it would never get executed in the flow.

Comment: He are closing the last if. Inside else if exists another if.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if ($name == "" or $email == "" or $password == "" or $cPassword == "") {
        echo "<div style='color:red'>No fields can be left blank!</div>";
    } else if ($name != "" && $email != "" && $password != "" && $cPassword != "") {
        $queryCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) < 1) {
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name','$email', '$password')") or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
            header('location:index.php');
    } } else if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) > 0){
        echo "<div style='color:red'>" . mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
        header('location:register.php');
    }
```

To

```
if ($name == "" or $email == "" or $password == "" or $cPassword == "") {
        echo "<div style='color:red'>No fields can be left blank!</div>";
} else{
        $queryCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email'"); 
        if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) < 1) {
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name','$email', '$password')") or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
            header('location:index.php');
        }else{
            echo "<div style='color:red'>" . mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck) or die("Error: " . mysqli_errno());
            header('location:register.php');
        }
}
```

Your if/else statment are messy.